# Cannot compare two same type enums in MSVC2008

Tags: c++, enums, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I want to compare two enums of same type with "<=" operator but it gives error.

```
// Logger.h
namespace MT
{
class Logger
{
public:
  enum LogLevel
  {
    LogLevel_None = 0,
    LogLevel_Error = 1,
    LogLevel_Warning = 2,
    LogLevel_Info = 3,
    LogLevel_Debug = 4
  };

void log(LogLevel targetLevel,std::string time = "",std::string className = "", std::string functionName = "", std::string message = "");

private:
  LogLevel level;
};
}

// Logger.cpp
void MT::Logger::log(LogLevel targetLevel,std::string time, std::string className, std::string functionName, std::string message)
{
     .
     .
     .
     if(targetLevel <= level)   // THIS LINE GIVES ERROR
     .
     .
     .    
}
```

The error is:

```
error C2676: binary '<=' : 'MT::Logger::LogLevel' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Why do I get this error? Isn't it safe to compare enums with relational operators? Note that when I static_cast to enums in error line, it gives another compiler error.

Please, help me to compare enums.

EDIT: The problem is SOLVED, however; I cannot explain how it did. I got this error when I was trying to modify my existing Logger class to singleton so now, I finished this modification and the error disappeared. Anyway, thank you for your consideration and @Bo Persson let's make peace.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error : http://ideone.com/JbGrVM

Comment: I think it requires some explicit type for it. `enum ENUM : size_t { E1, E2, E3};`

Comment: @javaLover because it's not msvc compiler obviously

Comment: offtop: Why name you should write `LogLevel::LogLevel_Debug` instead of `LogLevel::Debug`

Comment: @Sugar Please elaborate. I think you know better (I am quite new for C++).  Do you mean compiler bug?  Is it related to version of C++?

Comment: @javaLover it's not a compiler bug. `C2676` is specific msvc compiler error. Ideone offers to use gcc as compiler and you cannot reproduce it. watch for tags. There's VS2008 in it

Comment: Works fine with VS2017. Time for an upgrade?

Comment: @Bo Persson Please, do not write such kind of comments any more for any one else because do you really think any one working with VS2008 in these days is really dying to work with VS2008? I have to because the client has a product that has been developed with VS2008 and I am developing a component that will be integrated into it. So, I am compelled to deal with.

Comment: @Sugar I do not understand what you mean. Can you explain a little more, please? By the way, it is "LogLevel_Debug" since once "enum LogLevel" was defined outside of the Logger class but in Logger.h. Then, I moved it to Logger class so I will rename it as soon as I resolve this problem.

Comment: Should work just fine like that (does for my compiler at least), but why don't you simply either cast the enums to char or unsigned int or define the operator <= for now? (if that is what you did and you only want to get to the bottom of this, forget my comment)

Comment: @mualloc - I'm just confirming that the code works for later versions of the compiler, and offer that as a solution to your problem. You didn't state that using a 10 year old compiler was a requirement.

Comment: @Bo Persson OK, I am glad for your interest into my question in your first sentence but the kinds of comments in second sentence should be avoided.  I always get such comments for VS2008 questions. I know 2008 is old and new versions of MSVC are free. I know. OK?

Comment: Convert both to `int` and it should work with your Compiler.

Comment: @mualloc i think older compiler requires explicit type conversion to able compare it. it means that you should explicitly convert it to some integer type (`int(targetLevel) <= int(level)` or `static_cast<int>(targetLevel) <= static_cast<int>(level)`) and/or explicitly note type for enumeration (`enum Name: int { E1 = 1, E2 = 2}` )